# Verify if a function is a linear transformation (R3 to R3)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have an algebra final exam on tuesday, and I'm having some trouble with this kind of exercise. I tried looking for an explanation in all over the web, but couldn't find anything of this type. Of course, I also searched a lot here, but really didn't find what I need.

Ok, so: I know that, for a function to be a linear transformation, it needs to verify two properties:

> 1: T (u+v) = T (u) + T (v)
>
> 2: c.T (u) = T (c.u)

This is what I will need to solve in the exam, I mean, this kind of exercise:

> T: R3 -> R3 / T (x; y; z) = (x+z; -2x+y+z; -3y)

The thing is, that I can't seem to find a way to verify the first property. I'm writing nonsense things or trying to do things without actually knowing what I am doing, or why I am doing it. I first tried to make two generic vectors, then tried to apply the function on it... but it looks horrible. Fun fact: I'm not having big troubles with solving R2 to R2 exercises, but I can't seem to find a way to solve this one.

How should I start to verify the first property in this kind of exercise? Note that in this case we shouldn't use matrix or anything, it should be just pure math.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1 (12/15/19):** Corrected spelling in the property no. 2 (added c instead of x), thanks for the suggestion.

**Edit 2 (17/12/19):** I passed the exam. I was wrong on some of the points, but was finally successfull in the linear transformation one. I didn't had to prove it, however. Just calculate the image and the nulity. Sorry for my bad english btw. Thanks you all for your help.

Comment: Matrix is pure math...

Comment: Hint: apply $T$ to the vector $(x+x', y+y', z+z')$. It should come out. (Spoiler: yes.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I would suggest using $c$ rather than $x$ in property $2$ of the linear transformation so you don't get it confused with $x$ meaning the first component of the vector in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: How do you go about verifying that property for $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$? Unless you’re using some unique feature of $\mathbb R^2$, the same process should work in any dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $v=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

Can you then show $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$?

Comment: I got to the point of just doing u = (x1, y1, z1) and v = (x2, y2, z2), then I made OK the sum of vectors, but after that I really messed up with actually applying the transformation on that. Anyways, the simpl0s answer was amazing and I'll solve it later (actually eating dinner). I'll post the solved exercise by myself when done. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Your vectors are in 3 dimension. When you are trying to verify $T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v)$ you just substitute $u = (u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3})$ and $v = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$ into the given transformation, in this case $T(w) = T(x, y, z) = (x + z, -2x + y + z, -3y)$, where $w = (x, y, z)$ in this notation, where we could have easily used $w = (w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3})$ as a notation, but I presume your course uses as axis label $x, y, z$. Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
T(u + v) &= T((u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}) + (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})) \quad \text{by substitution of vectors} \\
&= T((u_{1} + v_{1}, u_{2} + v_{2}, u_{3} + v_{3})) \quad \text{by defintion of coordinate-wise vector addition} \\
& = (u_{1} + v_{1} + u_{3} + v_{3}, -2(u_{1} + v_{1}) + u_{2} + v_{2} + u_{3} + v_{3}, -3(u_{2} + v_{2})) \quad \text{(1)} \\
& = (u_{1} + v_{1} + u_{3} + v_{3}, -2u_{1} - 2v_{1} + u_{2} + v_{2} + u_{3} + v_{3}, -3 u_{2} - 3v_{2}) \quad \text{(2)} \\
& = (u_{1} + u_{3}, -2u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3}, -3 u_{2}) + (v_{1} + v_{3}, - 2v_{1} + v_{2} + v_{3}, - 3v_{2}) \quad \text{(3)} \\
& = T(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}) + T(u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}) \quad (4)  \\
& = T(u) + T(v).
\end{align}$$

(1) by applying the transformation 
(2) some vector algebra
(3) recognizing what you wan to show and bringing into desired form
(4) recognizing this is the transformation applied to $u$ and $v$

Comment: I can see it much more clearly right now. Just saying that I will later do the exercise by myself and update it in the original post, so it can be useful for other persons. My biggest problem was the thing you did since the (1) step. Thanks you, really appreciate your job.

Comment: You're welcome. When working problems if you cannot "see" what you need to show in terms of equality, simply work it out forwards and then start working out backwards and see where you meet and what is left to be shown. Even though when we present the solutions we go from A to B to C to D but when working to get the solution we might get stuck from A to B and get stuck and then working from D to C backwards and meeting at B is a method of achieving the solution. If you haven't read I recommend reading George Polya's How to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do these types of problems is to show that T is equivalent to left multiplication by a matrix. Here we have

\begin{align}
T(x, y, z) &= (x + z, -2x + y + z, -3y) \\ 
&= x(1, -2, 0) + y(0, 1, -3) + z(1, 1, 0) \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0  & 1 \\
-2 & 1  & 1 \\
0  & -3 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}
Because T is equivalent to left multiplication by a matrix on a vector, T must be a linear map.